# Como cambio formato de input date a YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Por defecto me muestra

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

como lo cambio a

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

con html y jquery, gracias.

Comment: y ese input es de tipo `date`?  se llena con algún valor directo de la base de datos, además que has intentado?. Bienvenido por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Es de tipo date si y lo llena el cliente desde la pagina con sus datos

Comment: serías tan amable de indicarnos editando tu pregunta que has intentado?

Comment: Es que no intente nada porque no se como hacerlo, solo quiero cambiar el formato de DD MM YYYY (que viene por defecto) a YYY MM DD, solo eso. No hay mucho mas que explicar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos para esto debes usar algun script o una libreria como **DatePicker** de **Jquery**

```js
  $( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd');
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Fecha</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Seleccione la fecha: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Si te fijas su uso es  muy sencillo declaras un input tipo texto, el cual posee un id mediante este con **jquery** creamos o agregamos el **datepicker** y a su vez le doy el formato deseado, para mas detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación oficial:

[Jquery DatePicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

Comment: Gracias! sos el uno!!